# Is there a way to disable my.cnf vertical setting from a shell script running mysql?

Tags: mysql, shell, scripting

Because the vertical output mode of the mysql command is very nice, I've setup my environment to default the output to vertical layout.  I've done this by creating c:\windows\my.cnf that contains

```
[mysql]
vertical
```

Regrettably, all my mysql shell scripts also pick up on this setting, wreaking havoc with parsing the output of the mysql command.

Is there command-line switch or SQL I can use to override the vertical setting in my.cnf when invoking mysql from a shell script?

Specifically, I have a shell script that looks something like this

```
set SQLFILE=.\cmdelOldRecords.sql
set TMPCKTFILE=.\temp2.sql

:: get all "_aud" tables from database
mysql -h %1 --port=3306 --database=%MYSQL_DB% --user=%MYSQL_USER% --password=%MYSQL_PASSWORD% -B -N -e "show tables like '%%\_aud'" > %TMPCKTFILE%

for /F "tokens=1" %%i in ('type %TMPCKTFILE%') do (
    echo drop table %%i; >> %SQLFILE%
    echo commit; >> %SQLFILE%
)

mysql -h %1 --port=3306 --database=%MYSQL_DB% --user=%MYSQL_USER% --password=%MYSQL_PASSWORD% -B -N < %SQLFILE%
```

But my .\cmdelOldRecords.sql ends up with stuff like

```
drop table ***************************;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the -E (or --vertical) switch to get the client act vertical
this means you could try:

```
mysql --vertical=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your client  [overide the options of my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html) by having a ~/.my.cnf file.

I am not sure that all options can be overriden,  reading the man page I posted and/or experimenting will tell you.